# Matplotlib rectangleSelector - Set initial position

Tags: python, matplotlib, rectangles

I am working on a project on which I want to select an area on an image in order to do some treatments on this area. So I found this wonderful tool RectangleSelector of matplotlib. But what I want is setting the rectangle at an initial position on the image, instead of waiting for the user clicking a first area (for example a rectangle of 10x10 pixels on top/left of the image).

At first I thought I have to use `state_modifier_keys` but it doesn't seem to be this.

So, is it possible ?

An example (with plots but it is the same question) can be:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))


def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)


fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()                 # make a new plotting range
N = 100000                                       # If N is large one can see
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N)                    # improvement by use blitting!

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Without blitting

If you're willing not to use blitting, the solution would be to set the `RectangleSelector`'s patch visible (`RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)`) and set its extent to the data you want it to be (`RS.extents = (0,4,0,1)`).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))

fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()
N = 100000 
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N) 

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)


# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)

RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)
fig.canvas.draw()
RS.extents = (0,4,0,1)

plt.show()
```

#### With blitting

The above will unfortunately not work when blitting is used.
A solution with blitting would need to involve copying the background, then setting the rectangle visible, but setting the `animated` property to false. Then for the first time the canvas is drawn the rectangle is shown. However for later use we would need to set the `animated` property to True again. Hence for the first time a click happens inside the figure, we need to set the `animated` property to True and blit the canvas with a background which has been saved before showing the rectangle.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))

fig, current_ax = plt.subplots()
N = 100000 
x = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, N) 

plt.plot(x, +np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='b', alpha=.7)  # plot something
plt.plot(x, +np.cos(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='r', alpha=.5)
plt.plot(x, -np.sin(.2*np.pi*x), lw=3.5, c='g', alpha=.3)


# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
RS = RectangleSelector(current_ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                       button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)
fig.canvas.draw()
bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(RS.ax.bbox)
RS.set_visible(True)

ext = (0,4,0,1)
RS.draw_shape(ext)
# Update displayed handles
RS._corner_handles.set_data(*RS.corners)
RS._edge_handles.set_data(*RS.edge_centers)
RS._center_handle.set_data(*RS.center)
for artist in RS.artists:
    RS.ax.draw_artist(artist)
    artist.set_animated(False)
fig.canvas.draw()

def initclick(evt):
    RS.background = bg
    RS.update()
    for artist in RS.artists:
        artist.set_animated(True)
    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event",initclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I use animation but without blitting so your first solution is perfect ! Thank you.

Comment: The wonders of SO! I was almost tearing what little hair I have left trying to do this - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For matplotlib v1.21.1 and py3.7 this works (both with RS useblit=True and False):

```
RS.to_draw.set_visible(True)
RS.extents = (x1,x2,y1,y2)
```

Note the order of coordinates for rectangle: x1, x2, y1, y2 (not x1, y1, x2, y2!)